# Obtain email address from Sign up and sign in v2 Policy?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have Azure AD configured as an identity provider. I wanted to know if it is possible to have Azure AD pass along the email address of the user and pass that along as a claim in the token we obtain when users log in. If not, how can I achieve this, I am new to B2C.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure AD [Custom claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims) to issue the "email" claim in the Azure AD Token that is returned to AAD B2C. This claim is only populated if the user has an Exchange Online inbox.

If you are using custom policies in Azure AD B2C, you can output the claim into the claimbag using:

```xml
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="aadEmail" PartnerClaimType="email" />
```

Where the ClaimTypeReferenceId is the claimbag claim that AAD B2C will store, and the PartnerClaimType is the name of the claim in the AAD Token you want to parse.

If the users do not have an EXO mailbox, then you could rely on the users UserPrincipalName coming back from Azure AD. That is in the claim called `unique_name`. So you could map that in the [AAD technical profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant-custom?tabs=app-reg-ga#add-a-claims-provider) by adding the following:

```xml
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="upn" PartnerClaimType="unique_name" />
```

If you are using AAD B2C User Flows, map it as per the doc [step 11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant#configure-azure-ad-as-an-identity-provider):

- Email: unique_name
  or
- Email: email (if the users have EXO inboxes).

Comment: I'm not using custom policies for this, any recommendations outside of custom policies?

Comment: See the end of my answer which is in respect to User Flows.