# I need to get the email used for signing in to the MS sign in to my application code. How do I get it?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have an application that uses Azure AD sign in through MS sign-in page. However, once authenticated I want to get the email ID used for authentication to my application code so I can verify it against the application registered users.
Is there any way to get it?

Code:
Controller

```
public IActionResult SignIn([FromRoute] string scheme)
        {
            scheme = scheme ?? AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            var redirectUrl = Url.Content("~/");
            return Challenge(
                new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUrl },
                scheme);
        }
```

Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

            services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";
               options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
            });
```

Login.cshtml

```
<li><a  asp-controller="Accountslogin" asp-action="SignIn" >Sign in</a></li>
```

Comment: Is the email ID used for authentication the same as username?

Comment: Yes, basically I am using MS Authentication and I enter email ID when the MS sign in screen pops up. Post MS authentication I need to match the same ID with the usernames registered in the app backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure you are collecting and sending the email Address attribute to the application.

User attributes are values collected on sign up. Claims are values about the user returned to the application in the token. You can create custom attributes for use in your directory.

[image]

For more detail information please refer similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62667559/obtain-email-address-from-sign-up-and-sign-in-v2-policy)

Comment: Please let us know if this answer was helpful to you. If so, please remember to mark it as the answer using the check mark so that others in the community with similar questions can more easily find a solution. Also, Please spare few mins to let us know how we did using this link <https://microsoft.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9?Q_DL=Fa5t8dkcKtAi0la_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9_MLRP_aY1vG5EZpoCCdEx&Q_CHL=gl
>